# Which complexity mb_strlen?

Tags: php, time-complexity, strlen

`strlen` complexity is O(1), because string structure save string length, but what about `mb_strlen`? And please explain me, why?

Comment: As I found out, the speed depends on the encoding it uses. In general, it does more work than `strlen`. It has not only to count the bytes, but they have to pre parsed as char. That's all I found out.

Comment: Since the string needs to be processed sequentially to count each code point, it's fair to thinks that it's O(n)

Comment: *strlen complexity is O(1)* - where are you getting this information?

Comment: apokryfos: Here (https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a0502b89a65d24eb191a7c85bcffcf9b91454735/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L637) look for strlen function and here (https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/41f5085e2ada1ad705084b8fd28b18bbc41891c0/Zend/zend_string.h#L42) for ZSTR_LEN macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6053987bc27e8dede37f437193a5cad448f99bce/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfilter.c) in worst case it is O(N).

```
mbtab = encoding->mblen_table;
n = 0;
p = string->val;
k = string->len;
/* count */
if (p != NULL) {
    while (n < k) {
        m = mbtab[*p];
        n += m;
        p += m;
        len++;
    };
}
```